# Minimax problem : uniqueness of a solution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, global-optimization

Let $n\geq2$. Is it true that the minimax problem:
$$
\min_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\max_{H\in\mathcal H}p^tH\bar{p},
$$
where
$\mathcal H\subset\mathcal{M}(n)$ is a strictly convex bounded subset of hermitian positive semi-definite matrices,
$\mathcal{P}$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb{C}^n$ not containing 0, has a unique solution ?

Is there a standard reference for general results about the uniqueness of a solution of minimax problems ?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you want  to normalize it, or to bound p to the unit sphere? Otherwise the minimum should be 0. (And maybe $\mathcal H$ should be   bounded).

Comment: Indeed, $\mathcal{H}$ is bounded, and the hyperplane $\mathcal{P}$ does not contain the origin.